# Table view and Predicates

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a table view with 40 objects. I have to filter them by gender when Click in a UISegment (male, female and both). It seems to be working, but table view does not refresh. Please any help would be appreciatte.

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

 self.navigationItem.title = @"People";   
    [self loadall];

  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FilterSortView" owner:self options:nil];

  self.filterControl.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
  [self.filterControl addTarget:self action:@selector( changeSegge ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}
```

#

My second method to filter by gender

```
- (void)changeSegge
{
    NSEntityDescription *personEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:personEntity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.people = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Could not fetch Core Data records: %@",error];
    }

    if(filterControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

        NSPredicate *predicatem =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender == %@", @"m" ];
        request.predicate=predicatem;

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [request release];
        NSLog(@"button 1");    

   }
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to fill people array after predicate set to fetch request.

Here is updated `changeSegge` method:

```
- (void)changeSegge
{
    NSEntityDescription *personEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:personEntity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.people = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Could not fetch Core Data >records: %@",error];
    }

    if(filterControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

        NSPredicate *predicatem =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender == %@", @"m" ];
        request.predicate=predicatem;
        self.people = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [request release];
        NSLog(@"button 1");    

    }
```